# How to color areas corresponding to a bump map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, color

[image]

Hi, I have got a problem here, the engraving on the right side was created using a bump map, but how do I color it? On the left side are the nodes that I am using.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a mix node to choose between the two colours you want, connect the bump image to the Fac input of the mix node.

[image: example coloured bump]

Comment: thanks, already solved 

| node used : https://i.imgur.com/m1f2NGB.png

| result : https://i.imgur.com/PnB6TDh.png